# What are the principal components of coconut taste, and how do they differ between fresh and stale coconuts?

Tags: fruit, coconut, fresh

I was used to drinking coconut milk and finding that it is nice, a bit sweet, and a bit bland.

One day i had a normal supermarket coconut, that tasted like Malibu essence inside. Is that what a very fresh coconut tastes like?

I am a chemist, and I am want to know if coconut aromatics vary a lot in between fresh and old coconuts, and if so, why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it hurts the "questions should not be a rant in disguise" rule, see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Actually, i am a chemist, and i am interested in Esters, freshness, savors, aromatics, consumer foods, industrial foods, food transport, maritime transport, seed biology, seed longevity, and my question has a scientific perspective, as asked to people that know about coconuts more than chemists do. I have lived in India and Indonesia where there are a lot of coconuts and didn't recall drinking a cocounut with aromatic coconut aroma over there, so i am puzzled why i found one in the UK.

Comment: where do you reckon the question belongs to on stack then . Biology? How can a quesiton about freshness and taste conservation of an edible not belong to the cooking forum?

Comment: Hmm, I'd have to think about a possible rewording. The problem is that taste is not a straight function of chemistry, and we don't have specialists in neurogastronomy here - so even if we were to reword it to make it more about the reasons in your different perceptions, we couldn't even establish whether this taste is something somebody else would have experienced, much less what the causes for it were.

Comment: I have edited the question to ask more for "what are the chemical differences which might point to an explanation" and be less inviting of a "why won't Big Food sell me what I want to eat" interpretation. Is it OK for you?

Comment: Ok perhaps it is an organic chemistry and biology question... It isn't so much about perceived flavor, because everyone agrees that shop coconuts milk doesnt smell like malibu, i figure it's about the loss of the aromatic gamma-Nonalactone in coconuts. the vapor of coconut is extraordinary (massoia lactone
  odor: Sweet, coconut meat, lactonic, creamy, milky and waxy
  flavor: Creamy, coconut, milky, green and slightly fruity) and if a coconut has or not is very noticeable and objective to everyone.

Comment: Hey thanks for the change to the question, sounds fine with me.

Comment: By the way, i would suggest, that if you think that question could be unacceptable because it is perhaps a rant in disguise, perhaps you are having a bad day and that you are seeing a possible rant in a totally innocent figure of speech. The question was worded about as simply and innocently as it could be. flavors volatilize, i wasn't inviting blame for the an explanation of why and how fast coconuts lose coconut ethylene, with due respect that was a negative interpretation of simple wording.

Comment: @comprehensible There are a lot of rants in disguise on the network. The fact that yours wasn't may possibly be the exception rather than the rule. Mods see a lot of bad content that you don't see because it gets deleted. Maybe you shouldn't assume somebody is having a bad day because they didn't react positively to your post.

Comment: *just passing along a few pointers* There is a flavor industry, since you're a chemist you can probably read the food science literature—at least if anyone has (publicly) studied it. Also, [MOFAD](http://www.mofad.org/) is currently doing a exhibit on flavor—maybe one of those folks could give a few pointers?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have more than a basic knowledge of chemistry and the information I have I translated from a [German book](https://www.amazon.de/Aroma-Kunst-W%C3%BCrzens-Thomas-Vierich/dp/3868514295) on spices and seasoning. All errors are therefore mine. The book is basically a description of a huge amount of spices, herbs and other seasonings, as well as a description of the chemistry involved which leads to the taste.

The difference in taste between coconut milk (if canned, as I assume) and fresh coconut water is easily explained. Canned coconut milk is basically a purée of coconut flesh mixed with water, which is why it has a different taste. Sadly, the book did not contain information on whether or how the flavour compounds (is that the correct word?) differ from coconut flesh to coconut water.

The book gives the following flavour compounds as responsible for the taste:

**δ-Octalactone** described as tasting creamy and of caramel

**γ-Octalactone** sweet and fatty

**2-Nonanone** fruity, sweet and earthy

**Limonene** lemon and turpentine

Responsible for the smell are the following (I have no idea what the letters and number in the parenthesis are supposed to mean, I'll simply include them):

10% **Caprylic acid** (C 8:0)

10% **Decanoic acid** (C 10:0)

50% **Lauric acid** (C 12:0)

15% **Myristic acid** (C 14:0)

10% **Palmitic acid** (C 16:0)

5% **Oleic acid** (C 18:1)

I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Ah, older coconuts are also described as tasting slightly soapy.

Comment: The numbers refer to the length of the triglyceride chain backbone, in carbon atoms (deca = 10)

Comment: Ah, I thought it was something along those lines, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fond attachment to coconut and can't do without it on a daily basis. I always use fresh coconut. Fresh coconut always is sweet and tasty in that sense. Also freshly squeezed home made coconut is tastier than store bought ones. The reason may be coconut has so much milk stored in the flesh which is tastiest when consumed fresh . Shelf life of coconut is not that longer if broken once. As days goes by it begins to get ripe losing the liquid content and dried up. You can very well taste the difference. Also if unused for a long time it gets spoiled, and the taste can be easily be found inedible. Ripe coconuts if not rotten can be sun dried and used in dishes it calls for, or can be used to obtain coconut oil. I hope it will all make sense only if you start using fresh coconut on a regular basis. Thanks.